# Unable to start ubuntu touch emulator. How to solve that issue?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, emulation

this error occur during start ubuntu touch emulator. [paste bin link here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11799625/)

Answer (score 1):

The main error is : ioctl(KVM_CREATE_VM) failed: Device or resource busy

Please be sure you have not another program running which issue virtual machine capabilities like Virtualbox.